# OrmLite pasing data do SP like object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to consume store procedure with ormLite just buy passing object, without using Parameters.Add. Something like this. But this trow error Procedure or function 'SuspendUser' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

```
db.Query<User>("SuspendUser", new { ID = 21 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/servicestack/4LumYfvaNxU/GpTY76hjCncJ) which (unless it has changed since) may be interesting. In particular, note the "dapper" syntax he remarks on, which would translate as:

```
var data = db.Query<User>("SuspendUser", new { ID = 21 },
   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: It is not working for ormLite. It is similar to ormLite but it is not working. I just found in documentation that ormLite doesn't support sending object to SP.

Comment: @Nikola yes, which is exactly what the discussion I linked to already said, and is why the discussion mentioned "dapper", and why I provided an example that used "dapper". BTW, dapper is a different library: http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper

Comment: Yes I know, I was hoping that there is something similar in ormLite, it is bit to late to shift to dapper but I will use him on next project. I will test it now to see how it is handling

Comment: @NikolaGaić you are allowed to use more than one tool ;p

Comment: Lol good point. I have just tried it and it is working like charm on test SP. Tnx Marc